# what is the best way to define label and TextBox

Tags: wpf

I can do it by define UserControl that will contain those 2 element. 
But is it possible to define it by define new style ?

I want to define something like on the bitmap attached. 
But i need to do it on a lot of places on my xaml.

[image]

Comment: If you want to use it on a lot of places,  I suggest making it a usercontrol or even a custom control if you want more power. Else you can just get away with a control template

Comment: can you please explain how to use the control template on my case ?

Comment: i want some example of how to do it by using control template

Comment: I answered a question today with [an example which illustrates this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38209371/424129).

Comment: I would suggest to keep both separate. Bcoz you may face issues when it comes to align with other controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by using a style for a `HeaderedContentControl`

```
    <HeaderedContentControl Header="Title" Content="what is the best way to define label and TextBox">
        <HeaderedContentControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="HeaderedContentControl">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </HeaderedContentControl.Template>
    </HeaderedContentControl>
```